# Combine Drag and Drop and Scaling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I've implemented a movable image view that I can move around with a finger and also scale. I use the drag and drop framework to move it around (because I also need it drag and droppable), and I have a `ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` that handles the scaling. The `MovableImageView` extends the normal `ImageView` form Android. When a user touches the image view, the method [onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) is called. This method looks like this:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
   scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
   startDragNDrop();
   return true;
}
```

`startDragNDrop()` looks like this:

```
private void startDragNDrop() {
    // Create a new ClipData.
    // This is done in two steps to provide clarity. The convenience method
    // ClipData.newPlainText() can create a plain text ClipData in one step.

    // Create a new ClipData.Item from the ImageView object's tag
    ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item(mediaItem.getMediaIdentifier());

    // Create a new ClipData using the tag as a label, the plain text MIME type, and
    // the already-created item. This will create a new ClipDescription object within the
    // ClipData, and set its MIME type entry to "text/plain"
    String[] mimeType =  {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};
    ClipData dragData = new ClipData((CharSequence) this.getTag(),mimeType,item);

    // Instantiates the drag shadow builder.
    DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new ZPACDragShadowBuilder(this);

    actualyDraggedView = this;

    // Starts the drag
    this.startDrag(dragData,  // the data to be dragged
                   myShadow,  // the drag shadow builder
                   null,      // no need to use local data
                   0);        // flags (not currently used, set to 0)
}
```

It basically creates the dragshadow and starts the dragging operation.

The implementation of [onScale()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener.html#onScale%28android.view.ScaleGestureDetector%29), that is called after `scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event)` is the following:

```
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    float scaleFactor = MovableImageView.this.SCALE_FACTOR;
    scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

    // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
    scaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scaleFactor, 2.0f));

    int width = (int) (MovableImageView.this.getWidth()*scaleFactor);
    int height = (int) (MovableImageView.this.getHeight()*scaleFactor);

    Log.e("MovableImageView", "Scale Gesture Captured. Scaling Factor " + scaleFactor + " old width " + MovableImageView.this.getWidth() + ", new width " + width);

    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(width, height, MovableImageView.this.getLeft(), MovableImageView.this.getTop());

    parentLayout.updateViewLayout(MovableImageView.this, layoutParams);
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

The field `SCALE_FACTOR` is a float and the value is `1.f`. And `parentLayout` is an extended AbsoluteLayout that manages the position and the size of the ImageView on the screen.

My problem is that the scaling does not function, only the drag and drop. No scaling is performed, only moving around the view works. If I comment out the linke `startDragNDrop()`, then the scaling works, but moving around the view obviously not. Has anybody a better idea to combine these to things in an imageview?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have a similar problem

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I had to drop the scaling functionality eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Is your onScaleBegin method returning false? When I was trying to do something similar Eclipse created an onScaleBegin method which returned false. This tells Android to ignore the rest of the scaling gesture. In order to get Android to call onScale and onScaleEnd I had to make onScaleBegin return true. 
The other problem that I had was that according to the [Android reference for OnScaleGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener.html) onScale may never be called even if onScaleBegin returns true. I therefore put my scaling calculations in onScaleEnd. This solution works for me because I only want to adjust the scaling once for each pinch or spread gesture.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved similar result for what you seek. Maybe that snippet will help you:

inside the `onClickListener()`

```
AnimatorSet scale = resizeAnimation(v, 1.2f);
scale.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        v.startDrag(dragData,  // the data to be dragged
                new MyDragShadowBuilder(v),  // the drag shadow builder
                v,
                0          // flags (not currently used, set to 0)
        );
    }
});
scale.start();
```

ResizeAnimation():

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private AnimatorSet resizeAnimation(View view, float scale) {
    ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", scale);
    ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", scale);
    AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
    animSetXY.playTogether(scaleX, scaleY);
    animSetXY.setDuration(200);
    animSetXY.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    return animSetXY;
}
```

MyDragShadowBuilder:

```
 private static class MyDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {

        // The drag shadow image, defined as a drawable thing
        private static Drawable shadow;
        int width, height;

        public MyDragShadowBuilder(View v) {

            width = (int) (v.getWidth() * 1.2f);
            height = (int) (v.getHeight() * 1.2f);
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            v.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_LOW); //Quality of the snapshot
            Bitmap snapshot;
            try {
                snapshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache()); // You can tell how to crop the snapshot and whatever in this method
                shadow = new BitmapDrawable(snapshot);
            } finally {
                v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            }
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProvideShadowMetrics (Point size, Point touch){

            int halfWidth = width /2, halfHeight = height /2;
            shadow.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
            size.set(width, height);
            touch.set(halfWidth, halfHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        shadow.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```